# Postdrop cannot open public/pickup file error

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have an issue to send an email with postfix sendmail on Ubuntu 21.04. ( error mesage specified below)
Has anyone encountered a similar issue?
I would be happy for any advice or pointers.
Thanks!

OS: Ubuntu 21.04

postfix package: postfix/hirsute-updates 3.5.6-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.6-1]

When I try to send mail with postfix provided sendmail I get the following error:

```
                          ... # verbose output omitted
postdrop: fifo_trigger: open public/pickup: cannot open file: No such device or address
postdrop: send attr status = 0
postdrop: send attr reason =
postdrop: vstream_fflush_some: fd 1 flush 18
sendmail: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 5 got 18
sendmail: /usr/sbin/postdrop -r -v -v -v: wanted attribute: status
sendmail: input attribute name: status
sendmail: input attribute value: 0
sendmail: /usr/sbin/postdrop -r -v -v -v: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
sendmail: input attribute name: reason
sendmail: input attribute value: (end)
sendmail: /usr/sbin/postdrop -r -v -v -v: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
sendmail: input attribute name: (end)
```

Pickup fifo in fact exists:

```
prw-rw-rw- 1 postfix postfix 0 Feb 24 12:29 /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
```

I tried also a variant with unix socket instead of fifo, but got the same error (only unix_trigger instead of fifo_trigger).

Following is my configuration (domain and IPs anonymized):

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
content_filter =
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
defer_transports =
disable_dns_lookups = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport =
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = example.org
masquerade_exceptions = root
message_size_limit = 28000000
mime_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
mydomain = example.org
myhostname = bastion.example.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, X.X.X.X/16, X.X.X.X/26 canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/README_FILES
relayhost = [mail.eclipse.org]
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = maildrop
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_use_tls = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

content of master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission    inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
 -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       300     1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix    -    n    n    -    -    pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
vscan     unix  -       n       n       -       10       pipe
  user=vscan argv=/usr/sbin/amavis ${sender} ${recipient}
procmail  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/procmail -t -m /etc/procmailrc ${sender} ${recipient}
discard      unix    -    -    n    -    -    discard
smtp-amavis unix -     -      n      -      4  smtp
     -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
     -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
     -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -      n      -     -  smtpd
     -o content_filter=
     -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
     -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
     -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
     -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
     -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
     -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
     -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
     -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
     -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
     -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
     -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
     -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
     -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
```

All the solutions I found online have pointed to configuration change I already have in place i.e.

`pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup`

or

`pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I used obsolete configuration directive `setgid_group = maildrop` in `main.cf` instead of `setgid_group = postdrop`